# How to redirect stdout output of specific thread to /dev/null?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, printf, stdout

I have one multithread application. there are common APIs and there are many prints on stdout for that.

I want for only one thread, this prints should not come.

How to do this c/linux?

Thanks
Rakesh Patel

Answer (score 3):

File descriptor is a per-process resource, not per-thread. So you can't redirect it only for one thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap `printf()` and add some specific code to detect in which thread you are, and if you may or may not print the formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a custom logger and just filter unneeded messages. It might look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthreads.h>

struct Logger
{
    pthread_t blockedThreads[256];
    int qty;
};

struct Logger *createLogger()
{
    struct Logger *logger = (Logger *)malloc(sizeof(Logger));
    logger->qty = 0;
    return logger;
}

void blockThread(struct Logger *logger, pthread_t thread)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < logger->qty; ++i) {
        if (logger->blockedThread[i] == thread {
            return;
        }
    }

    logger->blockedThreads[logger->qty] = thread;
    logger->qty++;
}

void log(struct Logger *logger, const char *message)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < logger->qty; ++i) {
        if (logger->blockedThread[i] == pthread_self()) {
            return;
        }
    }

    // DO REAL LOGGING HERE
}
```

I hope my idea is clear enough for you.

Comment: sorry, just wanted to express an idea, implementation isn't hard. but, I found a few minutes and tried to rewrite my solution in C.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [fprintf](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fprintf.htm) instead of printf and write to different FD for each specific thread

```
#define CONSOLE_ENABLED  (void *)(1)
#define CONSOLE_DISABLED (void *)(2)

void *Tsk_X(void *arg)
{
   FILE* console = NULL;

   if (arg == CONSOLE_DISABLED)
      console = fopen("/dev/null", "w");
   else
      console = stdout // or stderr that is unbuffered

   if (console != NULL)
   {
       fprintf(console, "Your strings");
   } 
}
```